# confused about improper lists in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I was wondering why

```
'((atom1) . atom2)
```

is the improper List out of the following selections

```
'(atom1 . (atom2))
'((atom1) . atom2)
'(atom1 atom2)
(cdr '(atom1))
(cons 'atom1 '(atom2))
```

Answer (score 3):

A proper list is either the empty list, or a `cons` cell in which the `car` points to a datum (which may be another `cons` structure, such as a list), and the `cdr` points to another proper list. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29#Conses_and_lists) for details. In this example:

```
'((atom1) . atom2)
```

`atom2` is not the null list, so it follows that it's improper. Let's look at the other examples:

```
; `(atom2)` is a list, so the whole expression is a list
'(atom1 . (atom2))

; it's a well-formed list of atoms
'(atom1 atom2)         

; the `cdr` part of '(atom1) is the null list, which is also a proper list
(cdr '(atom1))         

; consing an element at the head of a proper lists yields a proper list
(cons 'atom1 '(atom2))
```

Comment: how do you know atom2 isnt a list?

Comment: By definition, an atom is not a list. I'm assuming that the name `atom2` indicates precisely this: that it's an atom. Of course, if someone named `atom` something that is not an atom, I wouldn't have a way to know it :)

Comment: `atom2` is not a list, it's an atom. It can't _become_ a list - but you can put it _inside_ a list. This list is proper: `'((atom1) . (atom2))`

Comment: `atom2` is actually a _symbol_, so of course it's not a list. Remember your list is quoted, so it can't possibly be evaluated as a variable reference or anything.

Comment: so if I have any atom if i simply put it inside () it becomes a list? how would I add several atoms in the same list? (atom2 atom3 atom4)?

Comment: Yes, if it's a quoted expression. Like this: `'(atom2 atom3 atom4)`. Notice the quote at the beginning!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez `null` symbol? This isn't Common Lisp. :-) (In Scheme, an empty-list object is not a symbol. In CL, the `nil` symbol is used _as_ the representation of an empty list.)

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty Yes, `'((atom1) . '(atom2 atom3 atom4))` is the same as `'((atom1) quote (atom2 atom3 atom4))` and is a proper list. But I think you actually meant `'((atom1) . (atom2 atom3 atom4))`, which is also a proper list (`'((atom1) atom2 atom3 atom4)`).

Comment: Thank you very guys it really helps with your explanations.

Answer (score 2):

An improper list is where any `pair` satisfies:

```
(define (improper? pair)
  (and (not (eq?   (cdr pair) '()))
       (not (pair? (cdr pair)))))
```

In words an improper list is one where any pair is anything other than another pair or the empty list.

```
> (improper? '(atom1 . (atom2)))
#f
> (improper? '((atom1) . atom2))
#t
> (improper? '(atom1 atom2))
#f
> (improper? (cdr '(atom1)))
#f ;; (cdr '(atom1)) is not a pair - can't use my improper?
> (improper? (cons 'atom1 '(atom2)))
#f
```

Or stated inversely for any 'thing' (not just a 'pair'):

```
(define (proper? thing)       ;; the cdr of the last pair must be '()
  (or (null? thing)
      (and (pair? thing)
           (proper? (cdr thing)))))
```

Comment: the last pair with a pair in its `cdr` is not a last pair.

Comment: Adjusted 'last' -> 'any', which is closer but feels a bit wrong.

Comment: I don't think that's right. All the pairs in an improper list except the last pair are normal pairs. Besides, the name is not very good. is it `improper-list?` or `improper-pair?` or `improper-atom?` or what? :)  BTW your first code was OK; just the wording/naming was a little bit off. I've never saw pairs being referred to as "improper". But if we talk about lists, a list is improper if its last pair's cdr is not null?, that's all. :)